# How to show data in a random order using SQL query

Tags: sql-server, data-binding, datalist

This is the SQL query that is binding into my DataList. Can you please tell me how to return the data in a random order?

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(varchar(6), a.lastdate, 6) as lastdate, * 
FROM
   alz_jobpost AS a 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT * 
    FROM alzome_SuperAdmin AS b 
    INNER JOIN alzome_Renewal AS c ON b.S_id = c.supid 
    WHERE c.product = 'HI-TOUCH' AND c.Payed = 1) AS aa ON a.oid=aa.businessid 
WHERE
   a.status = 1 
   AND a.lastdate > GETDATE() 
ORDER BY 
   a.startdate DESC
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want this query to just return random results? Or do you want it in a random order?

Comment: random order of data  with startdate also order by dsc

Comment: Sorry I'm still unclear. You want it in a random order? But you say you want to order by StartDate? It is not possible to be random and ordered at the same time.

Comment: i have n number of records in my table...now its showing one by one as they exist in table...i want to show randomly in each page load

Comment: ok no issue with starting date...give me the query for show randomly

Comment: I have added my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your results in a random order you can change the:

`ORDER BY a.startdate DESC`

to something like:

`ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: if 100 records are can i get get all in random order?

Comment: This should provide all results in a random order. But it will add a performance hit. So if it is a table containing hundreds of thousands of rows it may start to create performance problems.